# How do I call a function with checked and unchecked a checkbox from a checkboxlist?

Tags: c#

I have a checkboxlist and i have to call function which perforform db job while checked a particular checkbox and unchecked a particular box. Plz help me out !!!!

Comment: Is this WinForms or ASP.NET? You need to be more descriptive, are you saying you want some code to run when the checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Answer (score 1):

what about this, if it is a web application:

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue == "your value")
              {
                     //do logic
              }                       

        }
```

Comment: I hav try this but how to take action on a particular checkbox

Comment: You can use the selectedindex to locate the item you need within the list.

Comment: why you want the checkbox you want only the value of selected index na .. please check my updated answer.hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

CheckBox.OnCheckedChanged Method (System.Web.UI.WebControls)
Raises the CheckedChanged event of the CheckBox control. This allows you to handle the event directly.

CheckBox.CheckedChanged Event (System.Windows.Forms)
CheckedChanged Event. Occurs when the value of the Checked property changes.

Comment: Your answer is relevent for a checkbox but what about, if Ihav to apply the method for a particular checkbox in checkboxlist.